# How to recover the Logarithm of rotations in the plane

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let
[image]
theta is the angle of rotation.

The Logarithm of this matrix is:
[image]

The way to prove this is just take the exponential of B:

exp(B); however I have no idea how to do it to obtain A?

I try to use diagonalization: (suppose n = 0)

[image]

How to go further? the first term and third term is 
one problem.

Comment: So you're looking for a proof that $e^B = A$?

Comment: The lower left element of $A$ should be $\sin \theta$, and $\alpha$ should be the same as $\theta$...

Comment: The $(2,1)$ entry of $A$ should be $\sin \theta$, not $\cos \theta$.

Comment: yes, sorry for this mistake

Comment: The way to do the diagonalization approach is: if $B = U D U^{-1}$, then $\exp(B) = U \exp(D) U^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an efficient way to solve this. Instead of using diagonalization, the approach
is as following:

1. Find inv(sI - A), where s is the Laplacian operator and I is the identity matrix.
2. Apply the fomula for L^-1(inv(sI - A)), we obtain:

   s/(s^2 + 1) = cos(theta)
   -1/(s^2 + 1) = -sin(theta)
   ...

Done!

I always consider the Diag. when facing matrix exponential; however, Laplas TF is 
sometimes a better and quick way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Taylor series of $\exp$ (hint: the powers of $\left[ \matrix{0 & -1\cr 1 & 0\cr} \right]$ have a simple pattern).  Or diagonalize...

Comment: Though if you diagnoalize, you have to do your computation over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.